# How to identify objects in micron units in regionprops3 comand?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, voxel

Suppose, I have a 3d image of (x,y,z)=(100,100,500) dimension. My task is to identify some objects in this image. I can identify objects using regionprops3 command from MATLAB. 
The confusing part is that my real x,y,z units are x=y=0.195 and z=0.387 micron. Whatever statistics I get from regionprops3 command that all will be in integer voxel unit. So, how to give my input image as in micron units instead of integer voxel unit to achieve object statistics in micron units. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example for the statistics from `regionprops3` command?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proportions of your 3D image must match the proportions of the real x,y,z units.

Try using `imresize3` for matching proportions:

`scale = (500/100)*(0.195/0.387) = 2.5194`
`new width, height = round(100*scale) = 252`

Assume `V` is your 3D image, try the following:
`B = imresize3(V,[252 252 500]);`

The statistics you get from `B` are going to be proportional to the real x,y,z units.

Note: `imresize3` interpolates the data, so the solution is not guaranteed to work.